# Change Excel cell's content type

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I need to change _Workbook's Range's content type from Text to Number. Because I can't use formula with text type cells..

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to do this with c#? what type of project are you using?

Comment: tags: WPF, C#... WPF project, for work with Excel I use "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

Comment: Did you set `NumberFormat` property like this ...  `_range.NumberFormat="0.0@"` ?

Comment: NumberFormat like this (0.0@) throw a COMException. But I tried another (smth like #.00) and effect comes only after copy-past all of this cells.... and it's not good for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use external libraries?
If you can, you can use nice [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) project. How to set number format using EPPlus is shown [here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample).

Comment: Yes, that's good idea, but I don't like to use external libraries if there is a native good one... If possible, I'd like to use Office.Interop.